# Prepend path prefix to all rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a setup where nginx serves a rails application inside a specific subfolder

eg. http://myserver/railsapp/ and everything inside gets proxied to rails, if the first subfolder is different, it servers static files from another folder.

I haven't been able to find how to specify this behaviour in rails in an intelligent way. I mean, what I want is to specify an option like `Rails.server_prefix = /railsapp` so that all the routes get prepended automagically, both on the incoming requests and on the generated links.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You probably want to use the router's scope method with the :path argument:

```
Rails.application.routes do
  scope(:path => '/railsapp') do
    # the rest of your routes go here
  end
end
```

[See the docs for more info.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope)

Comment: this would work for the route generation, but in rails 3.1, this won't recognize `/railsapp/assets/pic.png`...

Comment: well, now I understood the function of `config.assets.prefix` ... I had to put `config.assets.prefix = '/railsapp/assets'` and now it works!

Comment: You can also do
`scope path: '/railsapp' do` for a slightly simpler syntax in my opinion.
Thanks for this though, helped me out!

Comment: it doesn't work for me. the generated paths won't have the prefix